# Java 8 parallelStream for concurrent Database / REST call

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, java-8

Here I am using Javaparallel stream to iterate through a List and calling a REST call with each list element as input. I need to add all the results of the REST call to a collection for which I am using an `ArrayList`. The code given below is working fine except that the non-thread-safety of ArrayList would cause incorrect results, and adding needed synchronization would cause contention, undermining the benefit of parallelism.

Can someone please suggest me a proper way of using parallel stream for my case.

```
public void myMethod() {
    List<List<String>> partitions = getInputData();
    final List<String> allResult = new ArrayList<String>();
    partitions.parallelStream().forEach(serverList -> callRestAPI(serverList, allResult);
}

private void callRestAPI(List<String> serverList, List<String> allResult) {
    List<String> result = //Do a REST call.
    allResult.addAll(result);
}
```

Comment: This question has already been answered, however I would suggest you not to use a parallel stream to perform multiple API calls in parallel. See this question & answer for explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945324/difference-between-parallel-stream-and-completablefuture

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the operation with `map` instead of `forEach` - that will guarantee thread safety (and is cleaner from a functional programming perspective):

```
List<String> allResult = partitions.parallelStream()
          .map(this::callRestAPI)
          .flatMap(List::stream) //flattens the lists
          .collect(toList());
```

And your `callRestAPI` method:

```
private List<String> callRestAPI(List<String> serverList) {
    List<String> result = //Do a REST call.
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think in particular the *functional* aspect of this is instructive

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `.collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't shy away from synchronising access to your `ArrayList`. Given that you're accessing a remote service via Rest, I suspect the cost of synchronisation would be *negligible*. I would measure the effect before you spend time optimising.